# How should I visualize the data collected by Envers?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-envers

I'm a true beginner at the Hibernate (4.2) + Spring combo tasked to work on a sub-application that uses these to do facilitate some CRUD management in an administrator portal, so I am probably getting lost at a very basic step.

I have loaded Hibernate-Envers into the project to do audit-logging on a specific @Entity field. After adding @Audited to it Envers works as expected, adding data into the _aud table.

My goal is to show a list of all revisions to this entity to the administrators. I am not sure how I should go about it.

What I've tried so far is..

1. Create a new Repository class that I imagined would use the
   AuditReader to supply a list of all revisions through some new
   Service. However, I couldn't make this work without adding a new
   Entity for the History object itself - and I felt this was probably
   not the way to go.
2. Attempt to use an AuditReader in the existing controller for the the Entity. For the creation of an AuditReader I needed a sessionFactory that I tried to autowire into the controller, but this turned out not to be the right thing, as autowiring failed.

---

What is the preferred structure for gathering data from the envers *_aud tables to show them to the end-users on a webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Create a new Repository class that I imagined would use the AuditReader to supply a list of all revisions through some new Service. However, I couldn't make this work without adding a new Entity for the History object itself - and I felt this was probably not the way to go.

Let us assume we have some really silly basic entity like this:

```
@Entity
@Audited
public class BasicEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  ...
}
```

You should be able to construct two repository/dao components that both use `BasicEntity` as the entity-type here, but both internally operate very differently with those instances.

Your business repository component would have the `Session` or `EntityManager` injected and you use that to manipulate these instances calling `#persist`, `#merge`, etc.

Your audit repository component would also have the `Session` or `EntityManager` injected but would use that to construct an `AuditReader` and query the audit tables.

```
@Component
public interface BasicEntityAuditRepository implements AuditRepository<BasicEntity> {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Override
  public List<BasicEntity> findByRevision(Long id, Number revision) {
    final AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get( entityManager );
    // build whatever query and return the results.
  }

}

public interface AuditRepository<T> {
  List<T> findByRevision(Long id, Number revision);
}
```